# What is a "sample" in MP3?

Tags: audio, mp3

It is said, that MP3 frame contains 1152 samples. What is a "sample" then? A pair of values for right AND left channel? Or an individual value fro right OR left channel?

Answer (score 8):

The language that is used can get a little bit confusing.  The just of it is that each frame will have 1152 (or 384, or 576 depending on MPEG version and layer) per audio channel.  How that data actually gets stored is more complicated than a single value for each channel because of compression.

If you want to learn more I would recommend http://blog.bjrn.se/2008/10/lets-build-mp3-decoder.html for a nice, detailed blog that builds up the reader's understanding of the MP3 format for the sake of building a decoder.

You can also see http://wiki.hydrogenaudio.org/index.php?title=MP3#Polyphase_Filterbank_Formula for rather technical information.  Link is anchored to a section that says specifically: "Audio is processed by frames of 1152 samples per audio channel"  But the whole page describes aspects of the MP3 format.

Comment: Latter means that there are 1152 * 2 * 2 bytes in uncompressed stereo frame, right?

Comment: Yep. From the first link: "_When we’re done decoding proper, a logical frame will have yielded us exactly 1152 time domain samples per channel. In a typical PCM WAV file, storing these samples would require 2304 bytes per channel_"

Comment: Is there any relation between sample and the time?

Comment: "... will have 1152 per audio channel ..." 1152 of what?  1152 samples per frame per channel?

Comment: @jayarjo Typically, the sample rate is 44.1 kHz meaning there are 44,100 samples per second. MP3 also supports 32 kHz and 48 kHz ([source](https://id3.org/mp3Frame)).

Answer (score -1):

MP3 takes in 2304 16 bit PCM samples, 1152 from each channel, and essentially performs an overlapped MDCT on it, such that you get 576 frequency domain components per channel. Because it is half overlapped, the next MDCT transform will include 756 new and 756 old samples per channel, and output 756 samples per channel, so you get a 1:1 sample mapping from the time to the frequency domain.

The psychoacoustic model is what performs the lossy compression, and I don't know the details. The output of this gets huffman coded (which is lossless compression).

Each MP3 frame contains 2 granules of 576 samples (that correspond to 576 new and 576 old PCM samples). This means 576 samples per channel, or 1152 samples total. Each frame therefore corresponds to 1152 new PCM samples per channel, so [2304 samples](https://forum.pjrc.com/threads/38466-Audiolib-MP3). Each granule contains huffman bits for both channels, scale factors for both channels. The side information in the frame is used by the huffman decoder.

Sample typically refers to a point in time, so this would include both the left and right channels, but you can separate them.